# Issue linking g++-4.8 Mac OSX 10.8

Tags: macos, gcc, g++, homebrew, symlink

I downloaded gcc v4.8 from homebrew so that I could update gcc and g++ to 4.8 instead of using the 4.2.1 supplied from apple.

I installed gcc48 with the following command:

```
$brew install gcc48 --enable-all-languages
```

This installed all the required dependancies and when I run,

```
$gcc-4.8 -v
```

I get:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0/4.8.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc --datarootdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/share --bindir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/bin --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,java,objc,obj-c++ --program-suffix=-4.8 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-plugin --enable-lto --disable-werror --disable-nls --with-ecj-jar=/usr/local/opt/ecj/share/java/ecj.jar --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
```

I created the symbolic link using

```
$ln -s gcc-4.8 gcc
```

while in the /usr/local/bin folder and it created the symbolic link and

```
$gcc -v
```

gives me the same output as:

```
$gcc-4.8 -v
```

I tried doing the same thing with g++-4.8 and created a symbolic link using,

```
$ln -s g++-4.8 g++
```

and got no errors. But now, when I do

```
$g++ -v
```

I get:

```
g++-4.8: error trying to exec '/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Here's my $PATH:

```
/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/Developer/Intel/ispc-v1.3.0-osx:/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
```

It seems to be looking for 4.2 for some reason and I have no idea why! It worked perfectly fine for gcc and am just not sure what is the problem with g++?

```
which g++
```

returns

```
/usr/local/bin/g++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me that your g++ symbolic link points to the wrong thing.
Try:

```
ls -l `which g++`
```

And if that looks OK, see if the target is not a symbolic link too, etc..

Be mindful that symbol links use relative paths. If you move a symbolic link around, it doesn't point to the same location anymore.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried `ls -l` `which g++` and that gave me this:
`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Apr 16 10:54 /usr/bin/g++ -> llvm-g++-4.2` and it was a symbolic link too. But isn't that by default?

Comment: Yes... that makes sense. But as you can see from my path variable above, I have /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin. So shouldn't that override?

Comment: Nothing as of now. When I create a symbolic link for g++ at `/usr/local/bin` I get he error I mentioned above.

Comment: Oh. I am sorry. I removed the symlink because it caused the issue. When I recreate a symbolic link and run `g++ -v`I get the same error : `g++-4.8: error trying to exec '/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory`

Comment: I just don't get why it is searching for `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2` instead of looking for `g++-4.8`

Comment: I checked both the paths. `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/bin/g++`does not exist and `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/bin/g++-4.8` does not have symbolic links to it. It is the correct `g++-4.8` file.

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/bin/g++-4.8 --version` returns `g++-4.8 (GCC) 4.8.1` which is actually correct. But if I create a symbolic link to it, I still run into that error.

Comment: Ohk.. so I did something that somehow made it to work!! I removed the g++-4.8 link in the `/usr/local/bin` and recreated the link to g++. It seems to work fine now!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try running:

```
$ hash
```

And check if gcc is in the list. If it is you may need to run:

```
$ hash -r
```

If you use bash or:

```
$ rehash
```

For zsh. This refreshes the hash, which provides a way for the shell to find the command without rechecking the entire path each time.